# how to implement onclicklistener on InfoWindow on google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using this `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter` to show `image` on `ImageView` in the `InfoWindow` but I want to handle `sliding events` on it to show other `images`.

Here is my code:

```
public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
{
    public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(Bitmap pbitMap){}

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        ArrayList<String> lPhotos = new ArrayList();
        File file=new File("/sdcard/trip/");
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        int count = 0;
        String lname = "";
        for (File f: list){
            lname = f.getName();
            if (lname.endsWith(".jpg")){
                count++;
                lPhotos.add(lname);
            }
            System.out.println("170 " + count);
        }
        Bitmap mBitmap = getImageFileFromSDCard(lname);
        View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
        ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);
        markerIcon.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        return v;
     }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
        ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html#getInfoContents(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)), you should `setImageBitmap` in `getInfoContents` instead of `getInfoWindow`.

Sample code:

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        private final View myContentsView;
        boolean not_first_time_showing_info_window;

        MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
            myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

            return myContentsView;
        }
```

custom_info_contents.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imgView"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more details, please refer to [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/) and my project on github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-InfoWindow-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bjiang/map_ex/MainActivity.java#L28-L63).

**EDIT**

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually I am using get Info getInfoContents but i want to know which method is called when i onClick on the Window view. Please help me with this problem

Comment: You can implement `OnInfoWindowClickListener` and override the method called `onInfoWindowClick`. It will called. Please see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.html#onInfoWindowClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#info_window_events). For code please see the edit

Comment: tysm for your immediate response which clearly helped me out! :)